# How to obtain Azure AD token inside Office 365 Outlook (or office apps) add-in?

Tags: sharepoint, office-addins, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, azure-active-directory

I need the token in order to use office api discovery service (https://api.office.com/discovery/) to find SharePoint root url. 
Is it possible to get access to Azure AD token from add-ins (Outlook/Office)?

Edit(To make things more clear):
As I'm building a multi-tenant Azure hosted app that should be launched via add-ins, I will have to force users to log-in in popup and give consent for application. Login is mandatory since in office add-in's we cannot find out who the logged in user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the documentation here on how to retrieve an authorization token - https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest from Azure AD for the use of finding the root URL - also you can use the Microsoft Graph, which is the newer version of the Discovery service (more details about it again at the link provided).

Comment: I am currently trying that solution that I found via this link (http://simonjaeger.com/building-a-good-authentication-flow-in-an-office-add-in/), which uses the same principles as your solution.
It looks promising. I'll add further comments if needed and Accept your answer when I confirm.

Comment: My question has not given sufficient information in the first place. Solution you proposed cannot work because I dont have any information about client (nor ID, nor Secrete) because I need to have multi-tenant setup.

Comment: Another comment, I've managed to get the authorization token by redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize endpoint. I'll accept your answer.